# How to pass arguments to a powershell commandline

Tags: windows, powershell, arguments

Would appreciate it if someone helps me with the small task .  I want to pass a command line arguments to a powershell script(that is not a file ).

Suppose , i just want to pass an argument that messagebox will show.

```
powershell.exe -command  "$str=$args[0];[System.Reflection.Assembly]::
LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms');
[System.Windows.Forms.Messagebox]::Show($str);" 'foo'
```

I want foo to be shown in messagebox. I get empty messagebox. Perhaps i missed something small.

Comment: instead of `-command "code" arg`, do `-command "& {code} arg"`

Comment: thanks Mathias, it works!!!

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen please write your  comment as answer, so nobody else waste time.

Comment: @JPBlanc done.!

Comment: @MathiasR.JessenThanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the entire thing in a scriptblock `{}` and use the the call operator `&` to invoke it with an argument:

```
powershell.exe -command "& {$str=$args[0];[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms');[System.Windows.Forms.Messagebox]::Show($str)} 'foo'"
```